# How to check the length of input in handlebarjs

Tags: javascript, jquery, handlebars.js

I have check on handlebar:

```
{{#if-condition classname '==' 'back-btn'}}
                         data-toggle="modal" data-target-tmpl="#testeest"
                         {{/if-condition}}
```

So there are 3 or 4 input field on page.
i want another check on my existing code if input field is blank  SO I want it on **#if-condition**

I am open to use javacript or jquery

Answer (score 0):

You should check your input value against "", or an empty field, like so: `$('#whateverYourInputIdIs').val() == ""`. For example, in regular jQuery, I would use it like this:

```
if (classname == 'back-btn' && $('#myInputId').val == "") {
    //do things that happen when your classname is back-btn and the input id is empty
}
```

Comment: i am trying to do it on my condition like  {#if-condition classname '==' 'back-btn' && $('#whateverYourInputIdIs').val() == ""}} but its not working some syntex error

Comment: You have to replace `whateverYourInputIdIs` with the id of your `<input>` tag.

Comment: i tried like   {{#if-condition $('#questioner input').val() != ""}} and its giving error 

Uncaught Error: Parse error on line 150:
...    {{#if-condition $('#questioner input
-----------------------^
Expecting 'CLOSE_RAW_BLOCK', 'CLOSE', 'CLOSE_UNESCAPED', 'OPEN_SEXPR', 'CLOSE_SEXPR', 'ID', 'OPEN_BLOCK_PARAMS', 'STRING', 'NUMBER', 'BOOLEAN', 'UNDEFINED', 'NULL', 'DATA', 'SEP', got 'INVALID'

Comment: do you have to use handlebarjs? This query works fine for me if I am just using regular jQuery....

Comment: yes i knw but i have to use handlebar.js due to some reason